# will the data get deleted when updating an node pool to confidential?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp, confidential-vm-tag

I am considering updating an existing Kubernetes node pool in my cluster to a confidential node pool. However, I am concerned about the safety of my data during this upgrade process.

When I update the node pool to a confidential node pool, what happens to the data on the existing nodes? Will the data be erased or remain intact?

I want to ensure that my data is preserved and that there will be no disruption or loss of data during the upgrade process. What mechanisms does Kubernetes employ to ensure data availability when replacing nodes in a node pool?

Any insights or best practices regarding this process would be greatly appreciated.

Can Terraform be used to update an existing Kubernetes node pool to a confidential node pool while preserving the data on the existing nodes?

Comment: Are you using persistent volumes backed by external storage such as GCE PD, Filestore or GCS?

Comment: GCE PD and Gcs too
considering to change nodes using persistent disks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the terraform provider does not support confidential nodes.  There's an [open issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/13127) for it.

In terms of preserving data, enabling confidential nodes on an existing node pool is the same as upgrading the node pool.  So assuming you used PD or GCS as you mentioned, then the disks will be remounted to the new nodes during the upgrade.

Comment: got it.. 
the same will be applicable to the cluster level right.